# Emacs - Unable to tramp with a different username

Tags: emacs, ssh

I have the following setup in my ssh's `config` file:

```
Host my_username.remote
 User my_username
 HostName server.xxx.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/general_id_rsa
 ControlMaster auto
 ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p        

Host different_username.remote
 User different_username
 HostName server.remote.net
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/general_id_rsa
 ControlMaster auto
 ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

The above config works with no problem on the terminal, i.e. I can do `ssh my_username.remote` or `ssh.different_username.remote` and it will login on the remote server with the right credentials correctly.

However, when I do this in Emacs, I can login with my credentials, i.e. `/ssh:my_username.remote:/`, but **not** with `/ssh:different_username.remote:/`.

I should note that on my local machine I am also `my_username`. So the problem seems to come from using a different username.

Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Comment: You have an extraneous `/` in `/ssh:/my_username.remote:/`, yes?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure Tramp will supply default values when you don't specify parameters, in which case `/ssh:different_username.remote` would be translated to `/ssh:my_username@different_username.remote`.

I would think you'd be able to use `/ssh:different_username@different_username.remote`, even if it's not able to pick up the automatic config.

Comment: Thanks - I noticed that if I do `sshx:different_username.remote:/` it works (!?) -- notice that I use `sshx` (-X) and not `ssh`. I repeated the test multiple times. Strange

Comment: In that case I'm not confident in my answer. (I'm sure someone else will know better.) Do you have anything in `tramp-default-proxies-alist` ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that got copied correctly? (the `""ssh"` certainly seems wrong), but those are (HOST USER PROXY) triples, such that if you tell Emacs to connect to USER@HOST, it will automatically connect to PROXY first. I can't quite tell if that's a factor here or not, but it's an obvious point of difference between the two hosts.

Comment: Sorry - You are correct - it is `(("ssh" nil "/ssh:my_username.remote:"))`. I think I understand your point, although  I am not sure how I could use this in my case.